# How to consume only an ACTION_DOWN on onTouch and allow the default action for the rest

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

The objective here is to place markers on google maps.

I want to place the marker when the user does a longClick().

Problem. The long click listener does not have the data about where the user clicked. I can only know that he actually clicked. Also, if I use the touch event and I don't consume it (I require that for the map to use its default listener for the scrolling) I don't be listening to any other touch events, even if the touch resets. (that does not happen for the other events, afaik).

How to I know where the user did the longClick so that I can place a marker there in the map?

Comment: None of the solutions solve my problem. Could some1 help me? I cannot set a listener because my listener is lost every time the event is sent to google maps. I also tried to use the GestureDetector but still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   switch(event.getAction()) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       dosomething
       return true; // processed the event
   default:
       return false;
   }
}
```

this will allow you to process the ACTION_DOWN event, and have default processing for all others.

Comment: I already did that. If I do that I won't receive the other ACTION_DOWN. I don't know why. It was supposed to stop sending the rest of the events related to touch but not the ACTION_DOWN too.

Comment: you have to return super() if you use this in an extended mapview

Comment: @NikkyD "super" is the Object class. Object does not know how to handle it.

Comment: i made a class that extends mapview, in that class i grabbed the touch and there i have to give it to super -> the real mapview so that the map moves. But i can do everything i like and the map still moves

Comment: @NikkyD I tried a lot but it still does not work like when I change the zoom on the map....

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps to detect long click. The `onFinish()` method of the `CountdownTimer` is the where you need to place your code to add markers.

It will work for detecting long click, not sure whether it will override scrolling behavior of `MapView` ;)

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("action down", "action down started");
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2500, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
                countDownTimer.start();
                Log.d("action down", "action down ended");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                countDownTimer = null;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Does not work. By returning false the default happens but I don't receive any more events

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly the situation is with your implementation? and what exactly you need?

Comment: I need, at any time (I will never know in advance when), when the user does a longClick (or something equivalent to that) over the map, the APP places a marker where the longClick happened. I also don't want my event to become disabled/detached before or after my code is executed. With your code or his that does not happen.